# How can I generate a list of the numbers of users with Roles B, C, and D that have Role A?

Tags: views

My site has a large number of user roles.  To generate a list that shows the number of users with each role, I created a view of users and set a **Contextual Filter** to *User: Roles* and then *Display as Summary*.  This gives me a list like this:

- Role A (23)
- Role B (10)
- Role C (15)
- Role D (7)
- Role E (4)

What I would like to do now is to create a new view that shows how many users that have Role A have Role B, C, or D like this:

- Role B (4)
- Role C (6)
- Role D (3)

However, I don't know how to get *Display a summary* to work in this way.  If I add **Filter Criteria** such as *User: Role*, then only the count for that role will be shown.  However, I want to show the count of users for all roles given that the user has Role A.

Use case: On my site, users get roles based on their interests.  They also get roles based on how involved they are on the site (like here on SE).  I want to generate statistics on the role choices of my most active users.

Comment: In the clone of the first views  you can add a new filter "User: Roles = A" along withe the current filter. Hope this will get the output you are looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, I ended up having to make several views, each with a filter of Role = A, etc., as suggested by Praveen S's comment.